# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting (Python insert datetime into postgres)

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql

I want to insert datetime into postgres via python

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
start_time_format = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours =33)
start_time =  start_time_format.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
conn = psycopg2.connect(...*connect postgresql*..)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO table01(start_time_str) VALUES(%s);""", (start_time))
conn.commit()
```

I get the following error:

`cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO table01(start_time_str) VALUES(%s);""", (start_time))`

> **TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting**

I try to change other DataType(`text`、`character`、`timestamp without time zone`. ...)
But still Error:(

Comment: The problem is that the second argument to `execute()` is supposed to be a tuple.  And even though you have `(start_time)` in parentheses, that does not make it a tuple.  You need `(start_time,)` to make it a tuple.

Comment: This `(start_time)` is not correct. If you want a single element tuple it needs to be `(start_time,)`. Note the ','.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rectifying my previous response after reading comments from @AdrianKlaver and @JohnGordon. There comments should be taken as the correct answer, I am just modifying my response so that future readers do the right thing

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO table01(start_time_str) VALUES(%s);""", (start_time,))
```

As @AdrianKlaver and @JohnGordon mentioned, just watch out for the ',' in (start_time,) to pass it as a tuple to the cursor.execute()

Comment: No, this isn't the problem...

Comment: Thanks @JohnGordon and AdrianKlaver. . The tuple (value,) is a right way to do it.